# Calculate MASE for time series with multiple seasonalities

Tags: time-series, forecasting, mase, multiple-seasonalities

What is an appropriate way to calculate the MASE accuracy measure [(Link)](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5) for a time series with multiple seasonalities?

For example: daily data with a strong weekly pattern and annual pattern.

[image]

[image]

The naive seasonal forecast used to scale the error is only allowing one seasonal pattern `m`.

Using `m = 365`: we are not considering the weekly pattern anymore (365 is not a multiple of 7). 
Using `m = 7`: we are not considering the annual pattern anymore.

`m = 364` considers the weekly pattern and most of the annual pattern. 
Is that thought right?

Any other idea how to calculate the `MASE` for multiple seasonalities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using `m=7` based on a recommendation by Rob J Hyndman in the comments of this post [link](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/smape/).

> I suggest you pick the shortest of the seasonal periods and use it
>   with a seasonal naive scaling factor.

Thanks again Rob for your advice!